# Mock object for event while testing JS

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

My application uses plain JS, HTML, CSS and Jquery. I wish to test a handler and make sure it is called with the correct event, which is a button. How do I create a mock object for this event such event.currentTarget = Submit? I am importing expect from chai and sinon for testing.

If I do the below, I get syntax errors :

```
    const mockedEvent = ({currentTarget: {<button>Submit</button>}});
```

Comment: Im not sure you are using any testing library or not. take a look this https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom. hope this help

Comment: Thank you, will do